# How to insert thankyou_text in petition thank you email?

Tags: civipetiton, petition

We want the 'thank you message' in the petition sign up instead of the petition title in the thank you email sent.  This then allows for the thank you message shared after signing up to also be shared via email.

I've tried changing the code which stands at;

Thank you for signing {$petition.title}.

To

{$thankyou_text}.

But the code isn't retrieving the text from the petition.  I've tried some derivations but believe I haven't got the right code to draw this in.

Does anyone understand my problem and can provide a solution of the code that should be used?